# jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I ran into this error

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

And after a minute of googling found that the solution seems to be to start jupyter with `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000`

However when I do that using Anaconda Prompt it opens a different jupyter window with a different list of files (it looks like system files, stuff with a .exe extension).  This My existing Jupyter notebook and Jupyter lab don't register the increased data rate limit and Anaconda Prompt returns permissions errors if I try to open any of the files, add anything new, or upload existing jupyter notebooks.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this - any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

When you run jupyter again, you are creating another instance that doesn't know anything about the first one. If you take a look at the urls in your browsers, you'll see that they have a different number after the 'localhost'. Problably one is 'localhost:8888' and the other 'localhost:'.

The best way is to run

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and then you will have a configuration file at `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` that you can edit and it will work for all the instances you open. Increase `NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit` and just restart your kernel to have it working.

Take a look the [configuration documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html).